# Content won't resolve

Tags: android

I'm working through a book samples programs and i get the same problem whether I create and type the code or whether i download the code already typed, so i'm thinking it's a setup problem.

I get this error in each each class:

`setContentView(R.layout.menu)` where the "R" is underlined in red and the code won't compile. If i add `import android.r` like "QuickFix" suggests, the red line goes away from the "R", but then the red line appears under "menu" (in this example). The same behavior occurs in each of the 5 classes that make up the project.

I do have matching layouts for "menu" etc. And (to the best of my knowledge) I registered them as Application Nodes in the manifest file.

It's driving me nuts.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: what are the actual compiler errors?

Comment: i'm not sure its actually a complier error. the red underline exist in the source code, and i can't resolve them. when i try to run with the redlines in the code i get: "An internal error occurred during: "Launching trivia_app_config".
Path for project must have only one segment."

Comment: By any chance do you see any files with .out extensions in your resources?

Comment: I don't. I have .png and .xml files in my res folder.

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to import `android.R` as it won't resolve your resources. Just remove that import and try to compile again.

If you are working off a tutorial then also check to have the same resources as in the tutorial and also if you decide to name thing different then keep that in mind an reference them by your names.

Comment: if i remove the "import android.R" then the error redline switches from undelining "menu" (in the setContentView(R.layout.menu) example) to underlining the "R". It's like I can choose to have the red line error undelinging the "R" or the "menu", but can't have underline neither of them.

Comment: I just clicked the project name and said "Build project". Among the errors its shows are: "Project is missing required souce folder: 'gen'", and "Project cannot be built until buildpath errors are resolved."

Answer (score 1):

The R class is generated by Android and contains IDs for all resources in your res folder. Go to your AndroidManifest and locate the package= attribute on manifest.  R is in this namespace. So if the namespace is com.yourpackage.blah, you'll want to import com.yourpackage.blah.R;

Comment: each .java src file has the "package" with the correct namespace as the first line. this namespace corresponds to the namespace in the manifest file. if i try to import the namespace in each src file the namespace after the "import" command shows the whole namespace with a red error underline.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reason Eclipse was not autogenerating the gen/R.java file. I don't know why. One time it did generate the file, and a after Project..Clean and Build All everything resolved. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your file names under res, eg drawables, are OK. I had a file name with capital letter and that prevented the creation of R with the same reference errors that you got. I did not check the error messages and it took me a good 10-20 mns to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens to me.
It usually happens that I have been working with some xml element, and before clicking to a java document to hit "run" i just hit "run" while on the xml.  I don't really know what happens when you "run" an xml, but it makes this horible file called some_xml_name.out.xml.

DELETE THIS FILE!

This file is the reason why you get so many R related errors, since the Resources library is never really created, or something like that.

That is my advice, without actually seeing the error you're getting in the console.